# Get Current Record ID in URL field like ApexPage.currentPage().getParameter().get('id')

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, url, custom-controller

I have object XYZ__c where I have created one button-URL with formula

```
{!URLFOR("/apex/myVFPage?id="+**HERE I WANT TO PASS ID FROM CURRENT PAGE**)}
```

which we usually do using

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

**I want open myVFPage having record ID of my any of the ParentObject** record which can be Account,Contact,Opportunity, etc.

As I am adding my XYZ__c related list on above ParentObject, So I want this URL button should work same for all of them.
**When I Click on "myButton" on RelatedList of my XYZ__C on any of the ParentObject record
I want to access that ParentRecordID in myVFPage.**
So, is there any way to do so ?

Comment: I take it you have separate fields on your object for each of the possible parents? How many potential parents are there? Can each XYZ__c only have one parent?

Comment: I am having around 4-5 Parent there, where only one of them is going to be filled for one record. See Editied Question now for more.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I haven't fully understood you, but it seems quite simple:

```
{!URLFOR("/apex/myVFPage?id=_RecordId_&ParentId=ParentId__c)}
```

Where ParentId__c is a formula field which works along the lines of:

```
If(
    Not(IsBlank(Account__c)),
    Account__c,
    If(
        Not(IsBlank(Contact__c)),
        Contact__c,
        If(
            Not(IsBlank(Opportunity__c)),
            Opportunity__c,
            'No Parent ID found!'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Yes, You got exactly what I'm looking for. I am trying this one

Comment: There may be some syntax errors as I just typed it up quickly, but that should be it. Obviously you can alter the order of Account / Contact / Opportunity ID if needed, and even add other relationship fields to the formula.

Comment: When I click on myButton in related list I want ID of that Parent Record in the constructor and how can I achive that ? See Editied Question now for more.

Comment: You would need to check the current page URL for the object prefix (i.e. '001' for Account) and then pass parameters to your VF page based on which page it's being clicked from.

Comment: Yah ! that was my first idea which I was trying to avoid writing a bunch of lines. I think, have to go in that way only.

Comment: Or else you could put a validation rule in place to ensure that only one of the parent fields can be populated at once, that way ParentId__c will also match the ID of the record you're clicking from.

Answer (score 1):

I put a formula in my List myButton (URL)

```
{!URLFOR("/apex/myVFPage?"+ 
IF(Account.Id!=NULL, "aid="+ Account.Id+"&", "") + 
IF(Contact.Id!=NULL, "cid="+ Contact.Id, "") + 
IF(Lead.Id!=NULL, "lid="+ Lead.Id, "") 
)}
```

which gave me ID's of parent in my URL easily and when saving my record for child object I added

```
   public pagerefrence mySaveMethod (){
    obj.Contact__c=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cid');
    obj.Account__c=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('aid');
    obj.Lead__c=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lid');   

    myParentID=(obj.Contact__c!=null?obj.Contact__c:(obj.Account__c!=null?obj.Account__c:(obj.Lead__c!=null?obj.Lead__c:null)));    
       insert obj;

     if(myParentID!=null){
        return new PageReference('/'+myParentID);
     }
     return null;
}
```

and Bingo !!!! It worked.
Note : I have put extra '&' in formula line no-2 next to Account id, because when I try to access myChild object for Contact it shouldn't give an any error, and it also work well with Contact not having any parent Account too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a javascript button:-

```
window.location.href = '{!URLFOR("/apex/myVFPage?id=")}'+window.location.href.split("/").pop();
```